# Laravel Undefined variable

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm having a problem right now I can't display my likes in my view page.
This is the line (like_counter) i want to show on my view blade but once I call it i get undefined variable like_counter.

```
    public function getLikeCounter($post_id) {
    $post = Post::find($post_id);
    $number = null;
    $like_counter = \DB::table('likes')->where('post_id', $post->id)->where('like',!$number)->count();
    return View::make('layouts.viewvideo', ['like_counter' => $like_counter]);
}
```

View:

```
<span class="badge">{{ $like_counter}}</span>
```

Routes:

```
Route::get('/counter/{post_id}', [
'uses' => 'PostController@getLikeCounter',
'as' => 'counter'
```

]);

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nvm.. Fixed it by adding directly to the view:

```
<span class="badge">{{ $post->likes->where('post_id', $post->id)->where('like', 1)->count() }}</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
return View::make('layouts.viewvideo')->with('like_counter', $like_counter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
return view('layouts.viewvideo',compact('like_counter'));
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is on your code this line **where clause**:

```
$like_counter = \DB::table('likes')->where('post_id', $post->id)->where('like',!$number)->count();
```

*Laravel 5.2*

change this:

```
->where('like', '!=', $number)->count();
```

*Diff : WHERE `like` != null*

Answer (score 0):

An easier way would be to get the records and count it

```
 public function getLikeCounter($post_id) {
    $post = Post::find($post_id);
    $number = null;
    $like_counter = count(\DB::table('likes')->where('post_id', $post->id)
    ->where('like','!=',$number)->get());
    return View::make('layouts.viewvideo', ['like_counter' => $like_counter]);
 }
```